# Prevent login view display after login in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, authentication

I wanted to prevent user to be able to view Login page after login in MVC web application. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By checking if the user is already logged in or not.

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Login()
{
    //Display only when user is not logged in
    if (!User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        return View();
    }
    else
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }
}
```